# Django Orm implementation of connection between unrelated fields by geometry

Tags: django, postgresql, orm

I am trying to return the closest node locations to a starting node where the 2 database tables have no relation defined between one another. Therefore, I need to find a method to create a full cross join between the tables/subsets of data according to a filter or a facsimile of one.

Models:

```
class WaysVerticesPgr(models.Model):
    objects = CTEManager()
    id = models.BigAutoField(primary_key=True)
    cnt = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    chk = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    ein = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    eout = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    the_geom = models.PointField(srid=3857, blank=True, null=True)

    class Meta:
        managed = True
        db_table = 'ways_vertices_pgr'

class Pois(models.Model):
    objects = CTEManager()
    id = models.BigIntegerField(primary_key=True)
    name = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
    tags = models.JSONField(blank=True, null=True)
    geom = models.PointField(srid=3857)

    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'pois'
```

Query 1 - q1 - is getting points from the Pois table that fit any criteria, the result I want is the nodes inside the waysverticespgr table of the routing section of the database and return each node reachable in a set time (i.e. within walking distance <= 10 min) with the minimum distance from any of the starting nodes and annotate the resulting nodes with the actual distance. I have working sql for this query but implementing with django orm or django_cte or raw queries has so far eluded me.

Sql:

```
with q1 as (
    select 
        *,
        st_buffer(geom, 10*60*1.3) as c_geom
    from pois p 
    where p.name = 'Aida' --example query
    )
select 
    wvp.id,
    wvp.the_geom as geom,
    min(st_distance(st_transform(wvp.the_geom, 4326)::geography, st_transform(q1.geom, 4326)::geography, false)/(1.3*60)) as wlk_cost
from ways_vertices_pgr wvp, q1
where st_contains(st_union(array(select c_geom from q1)), wvp.the_geom)
group by wvp.id
```

I can't seem to perform any kind of cross join with django orm and haven't been able to get some kind of connection between tables to allow django orm joins to work in my favor.